# libquadmath.o.dylib found by gcc, but not mpicc

Tags: mpi, igraph, openacc

I want to compile some igraph code within a file that uses MPI and OpenACC. Using an igraph example (“sparsemat2.c”), it compiles with “gcc”, but not “mpicc”.

```
$ gcc sparsemat2.c -I/usr/local/include/igraph -o sparsemat2 -ligraph
$ mpicc sparsemat2.c -I/usr/local/include/igraph -o sparsemat2 -ligraph
ld: file not found: @rpath/libquadmath.0.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
$
```

Looking at the “-v” output, the two call most of the same include directories and link libraries. Is “libquadmath.0.dylib” somehow attached to “gcc”? Is there a way for “mpicc” to link to it?

System info:

```
MacBook Pro OSX 12.6.3
$ mpicc --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
$
```

Comment: Where did you obtain mpicc from? Homebrew, MacPorts? Did you install igraph yourself or with a package manager? Is igraph installed as a static or dynamic library?

Comment: `libquadmath` does come with GCC, and it's usually needed by programs compiled with gfortran. So here it's not a direct igraph dependency, as igraph does not include Fortran code. I have a note to use the following flags when linking to gfortran-compiled code and using MacPorts, but I do not have a full understanding of the issues: `-L/opt/local/lib/libgcc -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -Wl,-rpath /opt/local/lib/gcc12`. You'll need to correct the paths to match your system. With recent GCC, the linking happens in a way that paths needs to be specified explicitly for the library to be found.

Comment: do `mpicc --version` and `gcc --version` return the same output? if not, and if you use Open MPI, you can `export OMPI_CC=/absolute_path_to/gcc` and try again.